# Подружать iframe в модальном окне только после его непосредственного открытия

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, есть ли у кого пример реализации следующего: необходимо подгружать `inframe` в модальном окне только после его непосредственного открытия и выгружать после закрытия.

Код вызова:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#modalIframe" data-toggle="modal">Изменить пароль</a>
```

Сам модал:

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="modalIframe" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Заголовок модального окна</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="alert alert-info">Привет,
<strong>ниже расположено модальное окно.</strong>.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, а в чем проблема? Открыли окно, в коллбек-функции добавили iframe. То же самое при закрытии, только в обратном порядке. Дел то [на пару десятков строк](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/nb7Yg/).

P.S. И отформатируйте код в своем вопросе: выделить его и нажать [image]